# Python: Count total unique matches

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe

[image]

I need a count of how many unique values from 2018 are in 2019. 
In this case, the count is 3 (A, B, C carry over to 2019 form 2018). How would I do this with Pandas?

Comment: df = df.groupby('Value')['Year'].nunique() try this once

Answer (score 0):

Let us do `nunique`

```
s=df.groupby('Value').Year.nunique()
(s>1).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this solution

```py
df.Year.nunique(dropna = True)
```

for more details [click here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get-unique-values-from-a-column-in-pandas-dataframe/)